# Why Toast doesn't work with MaterialComponent theme?

Tags: android

When i use default `AppCompat`theme my toast works, but when i use Material theme, there error appears.

`Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView`

And when i change `Toast`  to `Snackbar` error disappears!!

Comment: With Material theme, are you referring to the Theme.MaterialComponents library?

Comment: Yes, i have `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` main theme.